# How to parse PCDATA and child element separately with PHP DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom, parent-child, pcdata

I'm trying to parse an XML of a dtbook, which contains levels (1, 2 and 3) that later on contains p-tags. I'm doing this with PHP DOM. [Link to XML](http://wwwlab.iit.his.se/c16linst/xml_api/finalassignment/test2/final_assignment.xml)

Inside som of these p-tags there are noteref-tags. I do get a hold of those, but it seems that the only results I'm able to get is either that the noteref appears before the p-tag, or after. I need some of the noterefs to appear inside the p-tag; or in other words, where they actually are supposed to be.

```
<p>Special education for the ..... <noteref class="endnote" idref="fn_5"
id="note5">5</noteref>. Interest ..... 19th century <noteref class="endnote"
idref="fn_6" id="note6">6</noteref>.</p>
```

This is the code I've got for the p-tag now. Before this, I'm looping through the dt-book to get tho the p-tag. That works fine.

```
if($level1->tagName == "p") {
    echo "<p>".$level1->nodeValue;
    $noterefs = $level1->childNodes;
    foreach($noterefs as $noteref) {
        if($noteref->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            echo "<span><b>".$noteref->nodeValue."</b></span>";
        }
    }  
    echo "</p><br>";
}
```

These are the results I get:

> Special education for the ..... 5. Interest ..... 19th century 6.**56**
>
> **56**Special education for the ..... 5. Interest ..... 19th century 6.

I also want the p-tag to **not** display what's inside the noteref-tag. That should be done by the noteref-tag (only).

So, does anybody know what could possibly be done to fix these things? It feels like I've both googled and tried almost everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DOMNode->nodeValue`](http://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) (which in PHP's [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/class.domelement.php) is the same as [`DOMNode->textContent`](http://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent)) will contain the complete text content from itself and all its descending nodes. Or, to put it a little more simple: it contains the complete content of the node, but with all tags removed.

What you probably want to try is the something like the following (untested):

```
if($level1->tagName == "p") {
    echo "<p>";
    // loop through all childNodes, not just noteref elements
    foreach($level1->childNodes as $childNode) {
      // you could also use if() statements here, of course
      switch($childNode->nodeType) {
        // if it's just text
        case XML_TEXT_NODE:
          echo $childNode->nodeValue;
        break;
        // if it's an element
        case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
          echo "<span><b>".$childNode->nodeValue."</b></span>";
        break;
      }
    }  
    echo "</p><br>";
}
```

Be aware though that this is still rather flimsy. For instance: if any other elements, besides `<noteref>` elements, show up in the `<p>` elements, they will also be wrapped in `<span><b>` elements.

Hopefully I've at least given you a clue as to why your result `<p>` elements showed the contents of the child elements as well.

---

As a side note: if what you want to achieve is transform the contents of an XML document into HTML or perhaps some other XML structure, it might pay off to look into [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). Be aware though that the learning curve could be steep.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! And the p-tags only contains noterefs so that wont be a problem.

Yes, I've tried with XSLT and that part worked perfectly with it. But I got some other problems when trying to use JavaScript to make the book turn pages and so on so I chose to work with DOM instead.

Comment: @lindastralberg Right on! Glad to hear it helped.